# Why after onAreaTouched call, onSceneTouchEvent() event is being called?

Tags: android, andengine

In an AndEngine game, I have implemented `onAreaTouched()` so that when an sprite is tapped, I detect and respond accordingly. Also, I have implemented `onSceneTouchEvent()` so that when user taps screen, I move the character. But I am having an issue. When user taps on some sprite, the `onAreaTouched()` is called but after that `onSceneTouchEvent()` is also being called resulting in two actions against one tap. I want that when sprite is tapped, only `onAreaTouched()` should be called and vice versa. I also tried to return true/false from `onAreaTouched()` but it did not worked. Any idea what do am am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the onAreaTouched() function is being called before the onSceneTouchEvent() function, you could just have a member boolean to control whether or not you want run the code in onSceneTouchEvent()

```
OnAreaTouched()
{ 
    mIsSpriteTouched = true;
    // then run all relevant code when the sprite is touched
}

onSceneTouchEvent()
{
    if (!mIsSpriteTouched)
    {
        //execute code that should run when the sprite isn't touched
    }

    mIsSpriteTouched = false; //reset for next event;
}
```

Comment: yeah, I was gonna do the same if some other solution provided by engine did not work. but thanks!